# Which of the two is grammatically correct, every possible situation or all possible situations

Tags: grammar

The code of conduct reflecting moral principles cannot provide guidelines or rules to cover [ every possible situation / all possible situations ], which creates ethics loophole that may be used by employees, possibly leading them to immoral and enthical behavior.

Which of the two is grammatically correct?  Are both acceptable?   Thank you always.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, both

> **every possible situation
>
>   all possible situations**

can be used interchangeably without loss of meaning.

As for the rest of your sentence

> which creates ethic**al** loophole**s** that may be used by employees, possibly leading them to immoral and **un**ethical behavior.